4G LTE USB device does not work on RHEL 9.2
I have a D-Link DWM-222 USB 4G LTE Adapter and I'm trying to connect it to my machine which has Red Hat Enterprise Linux OS (RHEL 9.2), in order to have internet. When I connect it to the machine, rarely I have internet, but most of the time it doesn't work. I compared the logs during two cases. And I noticed that when it doesn't work, the journalctl logs have the following lines:
Aug 27 16:45:59 user kernel: usb 1-1.1: reset high-speed USB device number 22 using xhci-hcd
Aug 27 16:45:59 user kernel: usb 1-1.1: device firmware changed
Aug 27 16:45:59 user kernel: usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 22
Aug 27 16:46:00 user kernel: usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 23 using xhci-hcd

When I connect the 4G usb to my ubuntu pc, it works without a problem, and sometimes when I eject the usb from the pc and connect to the machine with RHEL 9.2, I have internet, but only few times. Also when I eject it and reconnect it to the machine, it doesn't work again.
Looking at the logs, I'm trying to understand what causes the xhci-hcd reset the USB device and change the device firmware.
